# Displaying an image to a user using Xamarin and c#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently trying to display an image to a user using c# and Xamarin. I've done it already using Xaml, but the issue is I need to be able to create images dynamically, as I'm going to be creating and displaying several of them to the user. But at this point in time I can't get even a single image to display using C#.

Just to clarify, I have the image I'm working with saved in my resources, and the image displays itself when I'm using Xaml, so I don't think my issue is the location of my images, or a broken file path. Anyway, here is my code so far.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{

    Image bookcover;

    public MainPage()
    {
        bookcover = new Image();
        bookcover.Source = "/Users/sydthecoderkid/Projects/BooksForAll/BooksForAll/BooksForAll.iOS/Resources/BookCover.jpg";
        InitializeComponent();
        bookcover.IsVisible = true;
    }

    async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyTabbedPage());
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm missing a chunk of code up where I'm initializing the image, but I'm not entirely sure what. I've scoured the internet for two days now, but no luck so far.

Comment: Is your BookCover.jpg in an iOS asset catalog? or is it flagged as an ios resource?

Comment: first, you create bookcover but you never add it to the page's view hierarchy, so it will never be displayed.  2nd, if you are loading from a resource use ImageSource.FromResource().  3rd, paths should be relative to the root of your app, not the root of the Mac's filesystem.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for responding. I figured my issue had to do with me not adding the image to the page view's hierarchy. When you say to add it to the page view's hierarchy, do you mean by making a new stacklayout or something of the sort?

Comment: Yes.  But you still need to fix the path, what you’re doing will only work on the simulator

Comment: @Jason. Thanks so much- you're a lifesaver here. One last question- as I'm adding the image source to a layout, i'm getting an error, as it takes a view item and not an image. Any suggestions? And thanks for the tip about the path- that would've been a massive headache.

Comment: You assign an ImageSource to an Image, and add the Image to the layout

Comment: @SydneyKeating I suggest you can add image to use **Asset Catalog Image Sets**, there is one article about displaying image in Xamarin.Forms, you can take a look:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your MainPage class needs to inherit ContentPage.

Secondly you need to add `Image bookcover` either to some Layout or to the MainPage itself by using
`this.Content = bookcover;`